# How do I maintain good code organisation without sacrificing performance?

Tags: perl, performance, code-organization

I subscribe to the idea that variables shouldn't be initialized until right before you're going to use them. It makes it a lot easier to remember what a variable represents if it's by the code that will consume it, and it diminishes the chance that the variable will be misused between initialisation and proper use.

The problems comes when the use of that variable is inside a loop or two. Then, the cost of intialisation gets multiplied and it may begin to impact performance.

Within Perl (or generally, as appropriate), are their any neat little techniques that allow you to place the initialization of a variable within a loop, but such that it only gets initialized on the first pass?

I'd thought of something like:

```
my $variable = undef;
while ($outer_loop) {
    while ($inner_loop) {
       $variable = $variable || 'initial_value'
    }
}
```

NB: The implication is that `$variable` is not reassigned within the loop.

Now maybe it's me, but that seems a little inelegant.

So, here's my question: is there a neater way to do this, or do I just need to get overmyself and compromise on code organisation, or suck up that 'inelegant' solution above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To address issues in your comment (the variable is computed in a function):

- A standard technique for optimizing this sort of logic that you want is called **memoization** (of that function). Among other approaches, Perl has `Memoize` module, or you can do it yourself.

  ```
    use Memoize;
    memoize('slow_function');
    while ($outer_loop) {
        while ($inner_loop) {
            my $variable = slow_function(arguments);
        }
    }
  ```
- Also, if the function is always producing 100% identical value (by design) throughout the loop, simply do a poor-mans memoization by initializing the variable in a statement prior to the loop.

  If you have a loop 3 pages long (e.g. so long that having the initialization before the loop is a readability problem compared to inside the loop), you have a bigger coding problem than just the location of the initialization line, and need to re-factor your code in the first place.

  As an aside, if your only concern with placing the variable before the loop is the fact that it destroys the readability context of "this variable is only for use inside this loop", you can easily solve it by either:

  - Having well documented code - either name the variable accordingly, or add a comment to initialization line, or both.
  - Or, by naming a variable something like `my $default_value_for_next_loop = long_func();` , and inside the loop actually create a local loop variable initialized from that: `my $loop_var = $default_value_for_next_loop;`

Also, as far as your own approach (`$variable = $variable || 'initial_value';`);
I personally find that absolutely elegant and readable, BUT!!! I'm pretty sure that it actually performs **worse** than a straight-up `$variable = $default_value_for_next_loop;`, because it has a conditional statement instead of a straight assignment. But I can't be certain without benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to mull over those options and figure out which one is more appropriate for my specific module... food for thought.

Answer (score 4):

> The problems comes when the use of that variable is inside a loop or two. Then, the cost of intialisation gets multiplied and it may begin to impact performance.

Does it? Have you measured it? If your `$variable` applies to the code throughout both loops, then I would write your loop as follows:

```
my $variable = 'initial_value';
while ($outer_loop) {
    while ($inner_loop) {
       # ...
    }
}
```

That way, the reader knows that `$variable` is used in the following section of code, and what its initial value is. In your code snippet, the reader has to go find the *actual* initial value somewhere deep in the loop.

There is unlikely to be a performance problem here, but you should always measure the performance if that is a critical factor.

Comment: It does... it's not a simple assignment; the value is generated via a function call. I agree that, in general terms it may be better to measure the cost of the value generation and see if it significant, but I'm still interested to see if there are any other techniques that can /generally/ be applied

Comment: How often would you expect to approach that code snippet *without* going far enough into the loop to call your initialisation function anyway? Code that initialises your variable at the top of the loop is still doing the same amount of work, just in a different order. And, you won't have to check every time through the inner loop to see whether the variable is initialised yet or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're taking your guideline a little too far. The best way to stop misuse of a variable is to delay it's *declaration* until just before it's needed. (Thus limiting it to smallest possible lexical scope.) Delaying initialization doesn't prevent misuse; it just creates an opportunity for someone to use an undefined value, preempt your initialization with their own, or use your variable for a completely unrelated purpose.

If a variable requires an initial/default value, that should be done as part of the declaration if possible. This makes it clear that the variable has a starting value.

```
my $x = 1;
my $y = f($x);
```

Delaying the initialization implies that there isn't an initial value. That's fine if there isn't one or if you can't determine it ahead of time, but you sacrifice clarity by sneaking a `$var //= 'value'` in later.

For variables that need to retain their value across loop iterations you have to declare them outside the loop. Sometimes I wrap loops in an extra block to prevent those variables from leaking into the following code:

```
{
    my $i = 5;
    for (1 .. 10) {
        say $i++;
    }
}
```